# dyld: Library not loaded...reason image not found?

Tags: c++, osx-mavericks, sdl-2, xcode-6.2

I'm new to c++ and XCode, I'm using `sdl2` to create a window but when i compile it, it crashes giving me a thread.I have included `opengl.h` , `stdio.h` and `SDL2.h`. There are questions about

> dlyd:library not loaded but their different.

**Error Message:**

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2   Referenced from:
>   /Users/shayanrazavi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/c++_code-bbdyozxqxxdxosbxuyhcrqobxrkd/Build/Products/Debug/c++
>   code
>
> Reason: image not found

This is the code I used i couldn't get int main to be inside the code block for some reason but anyway and I got this code from https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  SDL_Window *window;                    // Declare a pointer
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);              // Initialize SDL2

  // Create an application window with the following settings:
  window = SDL_CreateWindow(
    "An SDL2 window",                  // window title
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,           // initial x position
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,           // initial y position
    640,                               // width, in pixels
    480,                               // height, in pixels
    SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL                  // flags - see below
  );

  // Check that the window was successfully made
  if (window == NULL) {
    // In the event that the window could not be made...
    printf("Could not create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return 1;
  }

  // The window is open: enter program loop (see SDL_PollEvent)
  SDL_Delay(3000);  // Pause execution for 3000 milliseconds, for example

  // Close and destroy the window
  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

  // Clean up
  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out why this was happening I was meant to put the framework in `/Library/Frameworks` folder before using it in XCode because when you download SDL it gives you a read me file and the read me file says to put it in that folder.

I should try reading all the text in read me files next time I guess. But if I try running this in XCode it will crash for some reason. (Makes sense because it says `dyld: Library not loaded and we just put it in /Library/Frameworks`)