# SDL2 installing on xCode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, warnings, sdl-2

I have downloaded SDL2.frameworks from https://www.libsdl.org and installed it into /Libraries/Frameworks/. Then I have pointed xcode a path of frameworks and headers in 'Build Settings',  in 'General' 'Frameworks and Libraries' pointed at framework file libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib . The I type #include <SDL2/SDL.h> and try to build the project. It shows 150+ warnings, but if I try to Run the program it says that Library not loaded. Why? what is the problem? I'm using Big Sur OS
[image: picture1]
[image: build settings]
[image: general]

Comment: Have you followed [the Lazy Foo tutorial](https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/mac/index.php)? It probably includes a step that you missed

Comment: @alterigel i did. But it shows me a new error now. SIGABRT it says that there is a reference. Ive deleted the files from the path an error was showing but still nothing helped. I don’t know. What to do. It’s been 9 hours I’m trying to solve this problem

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify exactly what you've done (if it's still relevant; it sounds like you fixed the compilation problems) and exactly what errors you're seeing.

Comment: i've tried to reinstall SDL2 many times. and errors are same. they are shown in screenshots

Comment: Have you seen [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633468/dyld-library-not-loaded-reason-image-not-found)? Looks like it could be the same problem

Comment: @alterigel he didn’t say what he figured out. I did many things. Like installed it with macports and with homebrew then i have put to Library/Frameworks. Nothing is helping. But with other program it works fine. I things it’s SDL’s fault itself. I am new to programming and i just follow tutorials I don’t know any other libraries :(. I am stuck now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out.

1. I have installed homebrew from https://brew.sh
2. I typed in terminal `brew install sdl2`
3. Then I have showed the path of framework (in xCode select project file >> build settings >> header search paths) and using `cmd+shift+g` type /usr/local/include
4. In General Frameworks & Libraries put libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib (its here
   /usr/local/Cellar/sdl2/2.0.14_1/lib)
5. And most important I have checked `Disable Library Validations` in Signing & Capabilities

After these steps code started to work for me

Answer (score 1):

You need to `codesign` the Framework.(The command by the Lazy Foo may be not right).

1. Find out one's own signature:

```
security find-identity
```

2. Sign the frameworks:

```
codesign -f -s "XXXX Your signature" SDL2.framework
```

Don't forget to sign the another hidapi.framework within the `./Versions/A/Frameworks`.

3. You can verify the signature:

```
codesign -display --verbose=4 SDL2.framework
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had same problem as the author @user14686569, although on newer version macOS Ventura. Due to few changes that happened to system paths, which also affected `brew`, I enhanced the author's with few simple tweeks to be more up to date for building projects with SDL2 library, and even more.

1. install `sdl2` via [brew](https://brew.sh/)

   ```bash
   brew install sdl2
   ```
2. in Xcode, go to your Project's setting into section Build Settings > Search Paths, like on screenshot.

   - add to section "Header Search Paths" -> `/opt/homebrew/include`
   - add to section "Library Search Paths" -> `/opt/homebrew/lib`

   [image: Project's Settings > Build Settings > Search Paths]
3. All set. Now, you should be able to find all libraries installed via brew, like following SDL2.

   [image: Project successful compilation]