# SDL2 Framework Linking in Xcode failing due to different team id's

Tags: xcode, sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to compile a very basic C++ app in XCode using SDL2 - and I'm running into a frustrating code signing issue that is not apparently solvable without disabling hardened validations (not really an option if you want to distribute your app). It's saying:

*not valid for use in process: mapping process and mapped file (non-platform) have different Team IDs*

Error below:

```
dyld[3678]: Library not loaded: @rpath/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2
  Referenced from: <35CBD752-6A32-3581-9662-6DE363C74AB5> /Users/alexei/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sdltest-fbdltneqiwmnclcteotuuilnactn/Build/Products/Debug/sdltest
  Reason: tried: '/Users/alexei/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sdltest-fbdltneqiwmnclcteotuuilnactn/Build/Products/Debug/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2' (code signature in <3F99A8E0-46D9-3192-9F62-E2C522BF5A24> '/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2' not valid for use in process: mapping process and mapped file (non-platform) have different Team IDs), '/System/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first install the [latest](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/releases) `SDL.framework` into your `/Library/Frameworks` folder. Then you must codesign it with your developer certificate.

```
cd /Library/Frameworks
codesign -display --verbose=4 SDL2.framework
```

This will show that the library is codesigned by someone else. For development, you can re-sign the library using your developer certificate. Get this with this command:

```
security find-identity -v -p codesigning
```

This will output something like:

```
  1) XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX "Apple Development: your.name@gmail.com (XXXXXXXXXX)"
     1 valid identities found
```

Take the part in the quotation marks, and paste it into this command:

```
codesign -f -s "Apple Development: your.name@gmail.com (XXXXXXXXXX)" SDL2.framework
```

Now, you can safely add the library to your XCode project **without** using `Disable Library Validation` (which will make your app undistributable).

For more background on codesigning SDL, check out these links:

- [SDL2 installing on xCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65657668/sdl2-installing-on-xcode)
- https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/issues-using-sdl2-on-xcode-on-macos/37776